# Another Delegate for ASIHTTPRequest Asynchronous?

Tags: iphone, delegates, asihttprequest

How can I create a new file containing just it's own delegate so that I can make an ASIHTTPRequest with its own asynchronous ending, and something easy enough where I just need to set `[request setDelegate:self];` to something like `[request setDelegate:AlternateDelegate];` and just add an include at the begining of the document to reference the AlternateDelegate delegate

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking - are you asking how to create a new objective C class?

Comment: Just trying to create another delegate for a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old, but in case anyone comes across it:

@Hankweb seemes to be talking about using a request as its own delegate. There are certainly situations where this works. For example, I'm working on a project that uses `ASIHTTPRequest` to fetch JSON from a remote source and import it into a Core Data store.

This operation (literally, as `ASIHTTPRequest` is a subclass of `NSOperation`) is almost entirely self-contained; I have a custom request on a background thread using a streaming JSON parser to import objects into a `NSManagedObjectContext`, which, when saved, triggers a notification that I catch internally and pass to the main thread's context using `performSelectorOnMainThread:waitUntilDone:`.

I'm using `ASIHTTPRequest`'s block support to accomplish this; in my custom `initWithURL:` method, I set up the relevant callbacks (`dataReceivedBlock`, `completionBlock`, `failureBlock`, etc.). The traditional delegation pattern (using the `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate` protocol) should also work, though.

One gotcha: you should make sure the request doesn't retain itself too many times, or else you'll end up with a memory leak. This can be easy to miss when using multiple threads, and especially when using blocks. Instead of:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *aURL) {
  //...
  [self setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self doSomething];
  }];
  //...
  return self;
}
```

Use the `__weak` attribute (or `__block` if you're **not** using ARC) when referencing `self` within the blocks:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *aURL) {
  //...
  __weak id blockSelf = self;
  [self setCompletionBlock:^{
    [blockSelf doSomething];
  }];
  //...
  return self;
}
```

If you don't know why this is important, make sure to read [Apple's guide to blocks in Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW3), and the [ASIHTTPRequest block API documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_blocks).

Answer (score 1):

A delegate for ASIHTTPRequest is just a standard objective C object. Just create a new class, include it's header, create/get the object and set the delegate to be that object.

Have you tried this and run into a problem? If so what is the problem?